# how to find control of mater page's button from Partial view in MVC Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I m new to MVC
I am facing one problem for finding control of button from partial view for a button in master page.
Can anyone tell me how can i find control of button from partial view

Thanks,
Sunita Saloni

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you are trying to do or possibly show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem when i use

> $('#Save').attr('disabled',
>   'disabled');

Answer (score 0):

I think you must be mistaken something here. In ASP.NET MVC server side controls (`runat="server"`) such as buttons are not used. A good place to start learning ASP.NET MVC is to go through the articles here: http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: i m not using server side controls For that i m using html controls

Comment: @Saloni, so maybe you can show us a little code about what you are using and how you are using it?

Comment: In the master page i m using two buttons  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="Save" />
                  <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Clear" /> and I want to find the button control from my partial view to check some condition and according to that conditions i want to disable/enable that button.

Comment: @Saloni, and you want to do this using javascript?

Comment: if it is possible with javascript then why not

Comment: @Saloni, yes, it is possible. Are you using some js framework such as jquery?

Comment: thanks friend i got the answer for this. I have used $('#Btn1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');